# Expiring TypedClient objects still leaves master set in redis

Tags: servicestack.redis

Imagine some code something like below...

```
using (var transaction = this.redisClient.CreateTransaction())
{
    transaction.QueueCommand(client => client.As<MyPoco>().StoreAsHash(myPocoInstance));
    transaction.QueueCommand(client => client.As<MyPoco>().ExpireAt(id, timeout));

    transaction.Commit();
}
```

I am storing myPoco as a hash within redis.  At this stage if you look at all the keys in redis then you'll see something like this...

```
ids:MyPoco
urn:mypoco:12345
```

i.e. The *urn:mypoco:12345* contains the myPocoInstance stored as a hash and the *ids:MyPoco* contains a set of pointers to each instance of a MyPoco stored in redis (at this point a single value of 12345).  This is all fine until the expiry kicks in.  As soon as *urn:mypoco:12345* expires then that hash disappears from redis which is fine, however the *ids:MyPoco* will never get updated to reflect that the 12345 entry is now gone.  So, as time goes by the *ids:MyPoco* will continue to grow.

Is there any way around this?
It seems to me that maybe it isn't a good idea to use expiry with TypedClients.  The only way I can see to get around this would be to not use a hash at all but instead just store all the individual fields on the poco as separate redis entries - however this isn't ideal.

I'm hoping I've missed something obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Expiring keys in redis happens silently on the server, i.e there's no callback you can register to clean up any related references which is why you should avoid expiring any entity that is referenced in an internal index unless you provide your own solution to periodically rebuild and clean the indexes, e.g:

```
var redis = (RedisClient)redisManager.GetClient();
var redisPocos = redis.As<MyPoco>();
var allPocos = redisPocos.GetAll();
redis.RemoveEntry(redis.GetTypeIdsSetKey<MyPoco>()); //remove ids:MyPoco set
redisPocos.StoreAll(allPocos); //recreate entities and index
```